# How can you solve a polynomial with a power of 1.99?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

$y_2 = -.0251256t^{1.99} + (v_{y})t + y_1$

How would I solve for $t$? Ideally I would approximate as a quadratic, but the error becomes too high.

Comment: If you substituted $t=u^{100}$, then you get a degree $199$ polynomial. I'd guess there is no known closed form solution (despite the fact the polynomials have very special form).

Comment: Numerical solution: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method), [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)

Comment: Are you interested in exact or approximate solution?

Comment: @Blazej I only need a precision of whole numbers, I figure I'll approximate it.

Comment: If no high precision is required then most likely changing $1.99$ to $2$ is not a problem. If this is not sufficiently accurate, then numerical methods will give you better answer. Winther already mentioned two good methods which can be easily implemeted by hand in any programming language. Even simpler solution is to use mathemathical software such as matlab or wolfram mathematica. These have plenty of solving functions already implemented.